# Building a realistic noise model in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, noise

I am trying to build a realistic noise model in Qiskit for a quantum computer that might be available 2-3 few years from now on. I tried to start from an existing noise model generated from a fake device, use `NoiseModel.to_dict()` method, tweak the dictionary a bit and load it back using the `NoiseModel.from_dict()` method. Unfortunately, the `from_dict()` method is now deprecated. Is there another method to adjust an existing noise model? There are several examples around on how to build a custom noise model in Qiskit, but I do not trust myself building a realistic one because there are so many settings that can be adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better manner to do that, but anyway:

You can generate a `NoiseModel` instance from an actual backend (or from [fake V1 backends](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers_fake_provider.html#fake-v1-backends)) by using the [`NoiseModel.from_backend()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit_aer.noise.NoiseModel.from_backend.html#qiskit_aer.noise.NoiseModel.from_backend) method.

Then it is possible to further customize the noise model using the methods and attributes of the `NoiseModel` class.

For example, this piece of code generates a noise model from `ibmq_quito` and alters one of its readout errors:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel, ReadoutError

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_quito')
nm_1 = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)

print('The readout errors defined before altering are:')
print(nm_1._local_readout_errors)

q0_RO_er = ReadoutError([[0.8,0.2],[0.2,0.8]])
nm_1._local_readout_errors[(0,)] = q0_RO_er

print()
print('The readout errors after altering are:')
print(nm_1._local_readout_errors)
```

This is an example for altering existing definitions. Adding error deifnitions is easier, and can be done using the `add_XXX` methods of the `NoiseModel` class (there are several).

Comment: Indeed, using NoiseModel __ dict __  method gives access to NoiseModel internals.

Comment: @Radu M. what do you mean?

Comment: The dict member provides access to NoiseModel internals. I used it to validate your proposed solution.